# How to restrict an sftp user to a specific directory AND give access to other users to that directory

Tags: linux

Inside a linux environment, I want to create an sftp user, restrict his access to a specific directory, and give full access to other users on that directory.

To create the sftp user and restrict him to the directory I followed https://kerneltalks.com/howto/how-to-configure-sftp-with-restricted-directory-access/.

To give full permissions on other users for this directory I used

```
sudo chmod 757 /home/username
```

Unfortunately, after that I have problem connecting with my user

```
iliamous@iti-628:~$ sftp sftp_user@xxx.xx.xx.xxx
sftp_user@xxx.xx.xx.xxx's password: 
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
Connection closed.  
Connection closed
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [OpenSSH man page](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChrootDirectory) all components of the ChrootDirectory path need to be owned by root and not writable by other users or groups. What you could do is bind the home directory into an empty root owned directory:

```bash
mkdir -p /srv/sftp/sftp_user/home
mount -o bind /home/sftp_user /srv/sftp/sftp_user/home/
```

Then you restrict the sftp_user to that directory:

```
Match User sftp_user
    ChrootDirectory /srv/sftp/%u
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -d home
```